# Can't use 'mark a' or 'mark A' in vim

Tags: vim

I like to use vim (on ms windows), I guess everybody have a favorite editor and this is mine.

On one particular PC I run into problems conserning the `mark[a-zA-Z]` command.
It does not work for the letters a and A but it does for b-z and B-Z and I would like to know why.

If I use the command `:marks` I can see that `ma` and `mA` do set an entry. But `'a` and `'A` have no effect. The same for the backtick versions.
If I do the same with labels b or B it works.

I checked my _vimrc but there is no line doing something to a or A.

What can block the labels a and A?
How can I find out what is causing this problem?

Any sugestion is welcome.

**Additional information: 5-mar-2016, 23:59**

I have no _gvimrc file and use the `standard' _vimrc file, never took the time to dig deep into the vim configurations. So it is still pretty vanilla. I like it this way, there are too many PC's I have to work with and synchronising _vimrc files is not what I'm looking for. :-)

This is in my _vimrc file.

```
:source C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc

let g:xml_syntax_folding=1
:filetype on
:filetype plugin on

:set foldmethod=marker
:set foldmarker={,}

autocmd FileType xml source C:\Users\andre\vimfiles\ftplugin\xml.vim
autocmd FileType python source C:\Users\andre\vimfiles\ftplugin\py.vim
autocmd FileType cs source C:\Users\andre\vimfiles\ftplugin\cs.vim
```

I have tried the suggestions made by cbaumhardt and that does not make any difference, running `vim -Nu NONE -U NONE`.

**Additional information: 6-mar-2016, 20:23LT**

The keyboard setting was interfering with the input. (`US-international`)
Changing the keyboard setting to `US` solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe a mapping overruling `'a`? What does `:map 'a` say?

Comment: @yolenoyer `:map 'a` no mapping found, same for `:map 'A` and no mentioning of any mapping on a or A in `:map`

Comment: First of all make sure if this is related to your `_vimrc` or not. To do so, start Vim with the command `vim -Nu NONE -U NONE` (without your `_vimrc` and a possible `_gvimrc`, in nocompatible mode). Try if `'a` works now. If so, comment out parts of your `_vimrc` to locate what is causing this.

Comment: @cbaumhardt Tried what you adviced on both vim and gvim. Started with exact your command line, then edited ten lines, numbered from 1 to 0 and did tried to put a mark on line 5. Both vim and gvim give me the same result, `ma`, move away and then `'a` fails but `mb` move away and then `'b` works fine.

Comment: Does `'a`create an accent in other programs? I've seen vim get confused by that before.

Comment: @FDinoff Bingo! That is the problem. Changed my keyboard configuration form `US-international` to `US` and the problem is gone. Problem solved.

Comment: PapaAtHome or @FDinoff post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operating system can intercept the key presses before vim sees it. So if you use an international keyboard layout, `'a` might produce a with an accent. Vim will not see `'a` which is why the mark doesn't work.

One solution is to map the character with the accent to `'a` or change the keyboard layout.

```
nnoremap <a with accent> 'a
```